# Cannot access my Ubuntu server on my local network, can remotely

Tags: networking, server, apache2

My ubuntu web server was working fine yesterday, But I tried to login via SSH today and it would not connect. I also cannot view my website by typing in the local IP address and I get no response from a ping. I can do all of these things using my external ip. Any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do any sort of firewall configurations on the server-side to ensure that only port 80 was forwarded to the web server?

If so, it's possible you've blocked the SSH port (port 22), or additional network changes (outside of Ubuntu scope) that are going to be very difficult to diagnose without some more feedback.

In short: What changed between yesterday and today?  ;)

Comment: The only thing I did was install PPTP VPN. Other than that I did not touch my server.

Comment: Ok, have you tried seeing if the VPN change, when removed, restores functionality?  I imagine it would.  If it does, you need to look into additional configurations for that software to allow the ports to work internally, possibly.

Comment: After removing PPTP it still wont let me connect from computers using SSH or web on my network via the internal IP. Is there any thing else I might need to change back from installing that?

Comment: First, did you reboot after uninstallation?  Second, if you try `sudo iptables --list` (after a reboot) on the server what results do you see?

Comment: Yes, I rebooted. [Result](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/4391/capture3ma.png)

Comment: Figured it out. The servers local ip is 192.168.1.10, I thought it was 192.168.1.11.....

Comment: Glad you determined it to be a non-Ubuntu issue.  ;)